# (OR) disables the earlier part of the condition

Tags: php, sql

An example for data in my table

```
post_id|post_title|post_status

1       i         1

2       love      0

3       sof       0
```

i've problem with (OR)

i am trying this condition

```
WHERE post_status = '1' AND post_id = '1' OR post_title = 'i';
//it should return with i
// but it returned with love,sof
```

The problem is caused because of (OR) at the end in the condition

it has been disabled the earlier part of the condition

So, How i can use OR properly?

i want search in posts by both columns, post_id and post_title

## NOTE:

i can't move `post_status='1'` to the end of the condition for some reason, it should be in begain

Comment: Use parenthesis to group the statements.

Comment: `A AND B OR C` is actually `(A AND B) OR C`.  It's the same mechanism that means `9 * 2 + 3` is `21` *[(9 * 2) + 3]* and not `45` *[9 * (2 + 3)]*.  If you don't put explicit brackets around the component parts, you need to be certain of the order of precidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to group logically with `()`, otherwise, the `OR` condition, whenever true, will supercede the required condition `post_status = 1` regardless of whether it is matched.

```
WHERE post_status = '1' AND (post_id = '1' OR post_title = 'i');
```

You should always be thinking about logical groups and precedence when constructing multipart `WHERE` clauses, but especially when making use of the logical `OR`, as it can quickly derail the rest of your clause.

Comment: Wow.. faster response i've ever seen in my live! Thanks Mr Iron Man

Answer (score 3):

`AND` has higher precedence then `OR`, so effectively your query is

`WHERE (post_status = '1' AND post_id = '1') OR post_title = 'i';`

And it seems you are trying to do:

`WHERE post_status = '1' AND (post_id = '1' OR post_title = 'i');`

So just use explicit braces